# Vaadin framework play video

Tags: java, video, vaadin

Can I play video using Vaadin framewotk ?
The main idea is loading video files from local drive in flv or avi formats and play it in web using vaadin framework.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a sample in the Sampler: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#FlashEmbed
You can see the source by clicking 'view source', and it will show you something like this:

```
Embedded e = new Embedded(null, new ExternalResource(
                "http://www.youtube.com/v/meXvxkn1Y_8&hl=en_US&fs=1&"));
e.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
e.setParameter("allowFullScreen", "true");
e.setWidth("320px");
e.setHeight("265px");
addComponent(e);
```

Obviously, you'll want to change the ExternalResource to something else (e.g FileResource, ClassResource, StreamResource, ...) in order to play local files.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have tried to play external videos like youtube and so on,  works good, but I have problem with playing internal .flv files, I've tried File, Stream and other resources , changed Mime Type to video/x-flv but result is negative :(. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin version 6.7 brought a new class [Video](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Video.html) that uses the new HTML5 "video" element to embed video on a page.

My [posting](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1106685) on the Vaadin Forum provides the source code for an example app.

The main part of that code, when populating a window or layout:

```
Video v = new Video( "video" ); // Instantiate video player widget.
// Specify a list of your video in one or more formats.
// Different browsers support various different video formats.
v.setSources( 
    new ExternalResource( "http://www.example.com/media/example_video.mp4" ),
    new ExternalResource( "http://www.example.com/media/example_video.ogv" ) 
); 
v.setWidth( "640px" ); // Set size of the video player's display area on-screen.
v.setHeight( "360px" );
this.addComponent( v ); // Add the component to the window or layout.
```

Oops, I just re-read you posting -- you want to play local video files. Do you mean local to the user's computer or the Vaadin app server-side computer? Either way, you may be able to manipulate the "ExternalResource" seen above, or another subclass of Vaadin [Resource](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/Resource.html) to access a local file.

Comment: I am using this Video class to view video files, but it is giving error "No video with supported format and MIME type found".
I have tried with .flv,.mp4,.mpg files, but same result. 
I am working with Vaadin 6.7.9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Embedded](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Embedded.html) Class to embed videos.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  This is for local files:

```
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(new File("/Users/user/Downloads/DBTI_1991_teaser_HD.mp4"));
        Video vd = new Video();
        vd.setAutoplay(true);
        vd.setSource(fileResource);
        this.addComponent(vd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the Vaadin add-on "[YouTubePlayer](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/youtubeplayer)" if you want to access a video specifically from YouTube.com.