# How can I embed a Youtube video?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I would like to embed a Youtube video in a Vaadin 8 app. The only plugin I found is MediaElementsJSPlayer which does not support version 8. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Emdedded` or `Video` classes to display video? Both of those should work.

For the `Embedded` there is an example here: [Vaadin framework play Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152719/vaadin-framework-play-video)
And for `Video` here at official sampler : [Video](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/video)

Also other StackOverflow questions on the same topic:

- [Play video in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355621/play-video-in-vaadin/25485699#25485699)
- [How to play video in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561222/how-to-play-video-in-vaadin)
- [Vaadin Framework play video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152719/vaadin-framework-play-video)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Label` with the `ContendMode` set to `ContentMode.HTML` to display pretty much every HTML content.

Example:

```
 @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        Label video = new Label();
        video.setValue("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"); // Replace this with your actual html
        video.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);

        layout.addComponents(video);

        setContent(layout);
    }
```

You can get the html to embed your video by clicking share and select embed.

Comment: If you want to embed video using `iframe`. then a better way to go is to use `BrowserFrame ` as descrebed here [Embedded Resources](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-embedded.html). There is no need to use label instead